# Area between two circles as a double integral in polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the area between the circles $x^{2} + y^{2} = 4$ and  $x^{2} + y^{2} = 6x$ using polar coordinates.

---

I have found that the equation of the first circle, call it $C_1$, is $r=2$ on the other hand, for $C_2$, I get that its equation is $r = 6cos{\theta}$. Then, to find the bounds of integration, I have found that their angle of intersection should be $\theta = \arccos(1/3)$ and $\theta = -\arccos(1/3)$. Then, to set up the double integral:

$A= \displaystyle\int_{-\arccos(1/3)}^{\arccos(1/3)} \displaystyle\int_{6\cos{\theta}}^2  \mathrm{r}\,\mathrm{d}r\, \mathrm{d}{\theta}$

However, when evaluating this integral with the calculator, I get a negative value. What would be the problem in this case? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 7):

You should have two separate integrals, since there is a change in the boundaries of integration, as measured from the origin.  You can also apply symmetry about the $ \ x-$ axis and write

$$ A \ = \ 2 \ \left[ \int_0^{\arccos(1/3)}  \int_0^{2} \ r dr \ d \theta \ + \ \int_{\arccos(1/3)}^{\pi / 2} \   \int_0^{6 \cos \theta} \ r dr \ d \theta \ \right] . $$

The "radial arm" extends to the $ \ r \ = \ 2 \ $ circle up to the angle $ \ \theta \ = \ \arccos(\frac{1}{3}) \ , $ but then "switches" to the other circle until $ \ \theta \ = \ \frac{\pi}{2} \ . $  Here is a graph of the situation:

[image]

The point is that for the region "between" these two circles, your "radius" out from the origin is not bounded anywhere by one circle as the "outer circle" and the other as the "inner circle"; you only change over from one circle to the second one.

**EDIT:**  I looked at your problem statement again, and then my graph again, and realized that the statement is *ambiguous*.  I interpreted this as "the area inside **both** $ \ r \ = \ 6 \cos \theta \ \ \text{and} \ \ r \ = \ 2 \ $ " [which I've filled with blue] .
The integral you wrote *could* be applied to "the area inside $ \ r \ = \ 6 \cos \theta \ , $ but outside $  \ r \ = \ 2 \  $ " [which I've now filled in orange].  In that case, your approach is correct, *except* that $ \ r \ = \ 6 \cos \theta \ $ is the "outer curve" and $ \ r \ = \ 2 \ $ , the "inner curve", so you should have written

$$ A \ = \ \int_{-\arccos(1/3)}^{\arccos(1/3)} \displaystyle\int^{6\cos{\theta}}_2  \mathrm{r}\,\mathrm{d}r\, \mathrm{d}{\theta} \ \ . $$

Was this in fact the area you meant to cover?  (Sorry if I misunderstood the intended problem.)  You have the boundaries swapped in the integral, which certainly explains the *negative* result.

Comment: Excellent answer, and just as a riff off of this, you can also observe that the area of the quarter-circle is $\pi$. Then you can subtract $\int_{\arccos(1/3)}^{\pi/2}\int_{6\cos\theta}^2 r dr d\theta$ from $\pi$ to get half of the desired area.

Comment: Quite so (you get to dodge doing two integrals in that approach, since you can simply take one area measure from classical geometry).  The important first step in these "area between two polar curves" problems is to have a good sketch of the region; as with so much other calculus problems, the picture is then useful in making choices about the calculation (and can suggest more than one method).

Comment: Sorry, folks, I went back and amended my answer, since "between the curves" here didn't make it clear _which_ region was to be covered (so now I have both...).

Comment: I am very sorry for the late reply. I was asking for the area of intersection (between the two circles). I did not actually realize that we would account for a larger part of the area when integrating as an upper bound $r=2$, and for a very small part of the area as an upper bound $r=6cos{\theta}$. I guess in this case it is very helpful to draw a precise diagram (and not the deformed circles I tried to draw).

Comment: Good to hear from you -- it's all right if you're only getting back now (quite a few questions here never get _any_ follow-up...).  Diagrams or graphs can be rather valuable at times because it can be hard to sort out the situation only by looking at the functions involved.  Also, "between the curves" in polar area problems can be unclear: in this picture, that could be the area in blue, the one in orange, or the one still uncolored.  It was only after completing my first answer that I realized what you intended using the integral you'd set up.  Glad we finally got what you were after...

Comment: +1 What software did you use to create the nice drawing?

Comment: @AméricoTavares I use the Grapher utility on my Mac; the color "fills" are done with Photoshop.

Comment: Many thanks for the information. I actually like it.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\!\!\!\!\!{\cal A}&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\Theta\pars{4 - x^{2} - y^{2}}\Theta\pars{6x - x^{2} - y^{2}}\,\dd x\,\dd y
\\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\dd r\,r\int_{0}^{2\pi}\Theta\pars{4 - r^{2}}
\Theta\pars{6r\cos\pars{\theta} - r^{2}}
\\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\dd r\,r\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dd\theta\,\Theta\pars{2 - r}
\Theta\pars{6\cos\pars{\theta} - r}
=\int_{0}^{2}\dd r\,r\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dd\theta\,
\Theta\pars{\cos\pars{\theta} - {r \over 6}}\tag{1}
\end{align}
where $\Theta\pars{z}$ is the [Heaviside Step Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).

> \begin{align}
> &\left.\int_{0}^{2\pi}
> \Theta\pars{\cos\pars{\theta} - {r \over 6}}\,\dd\theta\right\vert_{0\ <\ r\ <\ 2}
> =\left. 2\int_{0}^{\pi}
> \Theta\pars{-\cos\pars{\theta} - {r \over 6}}\,\dd\theta\right\vert_{0\ <\ r\ <\ 2}
> \\[3mm]&=\left. 2\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}
> \Theta\pars{\sin\pars{\theta} - {r \over 6}}\,\dd\theta\right\vert_{0\ <\ r\ <\ 2}
> =2\left. \int_{\arcsin\pars{r/6}}^{\pi/2}\,\dd\theta\right\vert_{0\ <\ r\ <\ 2}
> \end{align}

$$
\left.\int_{0}^{2\pi}
\Theta\pars{\cos\pars{\theta} - {r \over 6}}\,\dd\theta\right\vert_{0\ <\ r\ <\ 2}
=\left.\pi - 2\arcsin\pars{r \over 6}\right\vert_{0\ <\ r\ <\ 2}
\tag{2}
$$
In replacing $\pars{2}$ in $\pars{1}$, we find:

> \begin{align}
> {\cal A}&=\int_{0}^{2}\bracks{\pi - 2\arcsin\pars{r \over 6}}r\,\dd r
> =2\pi - 2\int_{0}^{2}\arcsin\pars{r \over 6}r\,\dd r
> \end{align}
>   The last integral in the right member is an elementary one: It can be easily solved after integration by parts and the final result is
>   $$
> \color{#00f}{\large{\cal A} = 2\pi - 4\root{2} + 14\arcsin\pars{1 \over 3}}
> \approx 5.3841
> $$